# nginx で他のドメインへ redirect したいのに、自分のドメインのディレクトリになってしまいます

Tags: html, nginx

nginx で、assets 下へのアクセスを、s3 にリダイレクトできないか試しています。

```
location ~* ^/assets {
    return 301 https:/s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/hoge-assets$request_uri;
    break;
}
```

Location に、望んているパスが返ってきました。

[image: レスポンス]

しかし、Chrome は、「元のドメインの下に、Location の値が入ったパス」にアクセスしてしまいました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Chrome, Firefox 共に同じ挙動でしたので、ブラウザではなく、nginx か、html が原因ではないかと考えます。html は下記です。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-d07f97160f917fd45d04dc4f95823689.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

1. nginx のリダイレクトは、return, rewrite の他に、適切なものがあるでしょうか？
2. 相対URL のリクエストを 絶対URL のリダイレクトで返しても、相対URLになってしまうのでしょうか？

#### 備考

なお、html のレンダリング時に 絶対URLを埋め込むべきなのは理解しておりますが、
歴史的経緯があるため、nginx でのリダイレクトを検討しています。

Comment: ご指摘とおり、単純な設定ミスでした。redirect で、絶対URLが返りました。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく "https://" としていない (スラッシュが1個たりない) のが原因です。